# communicate two different gnu radio files

Tags: gnuradio

My question is that is there any method to send data from a gnuradio file (or in the generated python code) to another one? There is a transmitter file and it transmits signals with different frequencies automatically. I know the transmitted frequency range and waiting time for each frequency. In another file I should make a receiver which should work synchronized with the transmitter while it does not know when the transmitter started. So , I thought if I can take data from other file, then it will be easy to make them syncronized by knowing the frequency range and waiting time. I will appreciate any comments and advices for different ways to communicate the files.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, considering transferring data between two devices is the very purpose of digital communications: yes, there are such GNU Radio programs/flow graphs.

What you need, however, is totally use-case specific. You'll have to implement that yourself.